# Angular 6 http not working with single JSON item

Tags: wordpress, angular

Trying to get Wordpress data into my Angular 6 component.

When I return a single post via Wordpress REST API it produces the right data (http://w3stage.com/tricap/wp-json/wp/v2/properties/174), but the data is not making it through to my template.

service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WordpressService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProperty(id): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://w3stage.com/tricap/wp-json/wp/v2/properties/'+id);
  }

}
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { WordpressService } from '../wordpress.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-detail',
  templateUrl: './property-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-detail.component.scss']
})
export class PropertyDetailComponent implements OnInit {

property: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private location: Location,
  private wp: WordpressService
) {
  this.getProperty();
}

getProperty(): void {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.property = this.wp.getProperty(id);
  console.log(this.property);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
}

}
```

template:

```
{{ property.title.rendered }}
```

This generates the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PropertyDetailComponent.html:8)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10782)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10158)
at callViewAction (core.js:10394)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10336)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10159)
at callViewAction (core.js:10394)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10357)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10154)
at callViewAction (core.js:10394)
```

However, when I adapt the code to return a bunch of posts from wordpress, I can get the data to work just fine in conjunction with an `*ngFor` loop. When I try an `*ngFor` loop with the single post result, same thing - no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use safe navigation operator or *ngIf inorder to handle the delay of response from your asynchronous request,

change your template as,

```
{{ property?.title?.rendered }}
```

also you need to subscribe to the observable,

```
this.wp.getProperty(id).subscribe(data => {
  this.property = data;
});
```

Comment: {{ property?.title?.rendered }} .  renders blank

Comment: @PhilipSmith yes

Comment: <div *ngIf="property">{{ property.title.rendered }}</div> also rendered blank